# Copy data from S3 and post process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

There is a service that generates data in S3 bucket that is used for warehouse querying. Data is inserted into S3 as daily mechanism.

I am interested in copying that data from S3 to my service account to further classify the data. The classification needs to happen in my AWS service account as it is based on information present in my service account. Classification needs to happens in my service account as it is specific to my team/service. The service generating the data in S3 is neither concerned about the classification nor has the data to make classification decision.

Each S3 file consists of json objects (record) in it. For every record, I need to look into a dynamodb table. Based on whether data exists in Dynamo table, I need to include an additional attribute to the json object and store the list into another S3 bucket in my account.

The way I am considering doing this:

- Trigger a scheduled CW event periodically to invoke a Lambda that will copy the files from Source S3 bucket into a bucket (lets say Bucket A) in my account.
- Then, use another scheduled CW event to invoke a Lambda to read the records in the json and compare with dynamodb table to determine classification and write to updated record to another bucket (lets say Bucket B).

I have few questions regarding this:

1. Are there better alternatives for achieving this?
2. Would using `aws s3 sync` in the  first Lambda be a good way to achieve this?  My concerns revolve around lambdas getting timed out due large amount of data, especially for the second lambda that needs to compare against DDB for every record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than setting up scheduled events, you can trigger the AWS Lambda functions in real-time.

Use Amazon S3 Events to **trigger the Lambda function as soon as a file is created** in the source bucket. The Lambda function can call `CopyObject()` to copy the object to Bucket-A for processing.

Similarly, an Event on Bucket-A could then trigger another Lambda function to process the file. Some things to note:

- Lambda functions run for a maximum of **15 minutes**
- You can **increase the memory** assigned to a Lambda function, which will also increase the amount of CPU assigned. So, this might speed-up the function if it is taking longer than 15 minutes.
- There is a maximum of 512MB of storage space made available for a Lambda function.

If the data is too big, or takes too long to process, then you will need to find a way to do it **outside of AWS Lambda**. For example, using Amazon EC2 instances.

If you can **export the data from DynamoDB** (perhaps on a regular basis), you *might* be able to use **Amazon Athena** to do all the processing, but that depends on what you're trying to do. If it is simple SELECT/JOIN queries, it might be suitable.